# how to Convert “unknown format” strings to time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to change the column of "Start time" format to Time format only but when i used the below code i found the below error message "Unknown string format: Annual"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcEcx.jpg)

```
FP_sheet=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Mahmoud.Bader\Desktop\FP Attendance V1.6 Apr 22.xlsx","Attendance").fillna("")
FP_sheet['Start Shift']=pd.to_datetime(FP_sheet['Start Shift']).dt.strftime('%H:%M %p')
FP_sheet.head()
```

Comment: How we're supposed to solve your issue if we have neither the data you are using nor which part of the code exactly is not working?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i've edit my code & provide you with a P.S for what i need to do also

Comment: You can't change to datetime while having this "Off Day" value. Every value should have datetime value
If you want to indicate whether a day is off day then add a new feature that has this information

Comment: is there any way to solve this issue, by using loops or any kind of formatting?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to select only rows without this text - ie `FP_sheet['Date'][ FP_sheet['Date'] != "Off day" ]` and later work only with these rows.

Comment: it would be much simpler if you would put example data as text in code - or better as `df = DataFrame(...)` - so we could simply copy it and use in solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter rows and get only rows with date - and later use only these rows

like

```
mask = (FP_sheet['Date'] != "Off day")

FP_sheet['Date'][mask] = pd.to_datetime(FP_sheet['Date'][mask]).dt.date
```

For more filters you can use `&` as `"and"`, `|` as `"or"`, `~` as `not`

```
mask = (df['Date'] != 'Off day') & (df['Date'] != 'Annual')

mask = ~( (df['Date'] == 'Off day') | (df['Date'] == 'Annual') )
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Date': [
        '2022.05.26 18:00',
        'Off day',
        '2022.05.16 18:00',
        'Annual', 
        '2022.05.06 18:00',
    ], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

mask = (df['Date'] != 'Off day') & (df['Date'] != 'Annual')
#mask = ~( (df['Date'] == 'Off day') | (df['Date'] == 'Annual') )

df['Date'][mask] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'][mask]).dt.date

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
-- before ---

               Date
0  2022.05.26 18:00
1           Off day
2  2022.05.16 18:00
3            Annual
4  2022.05.06 18:00

--- after ---

         Date
0  2022-05-26
1     Off day
2  2022-05-16
3      Annual
4  2022-05-06
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use `.apply()` to run function which will check if it is text - and return this text, or if it is datetime - and return date

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# --- functions ---

def convert(item):
    if item in ['Off day', 'Annual']:
        return item
    else:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M').date()

# --- main ---

data = {
    'Date': [
        '2022.05.26 18:00',
        'Off day',
        '2022.05.16 18:00',
        'Annual',
        '2022.05.06 18:00',
    ], 
}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(convert)
    
print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

if you want to check list

```
mask = ~df['Date'].isin(['Off day', 'Annual'])
```

Comment: many thanks for your support, the code works with me but what if that there's many different strings in the same column (OFF Day, Annual, Casual,...etc), how can i set must to not equal any string?

Comment: with normal variable I would use `variable in ["off day", "Annual", ...]` but I don't know if pandas has something like this. You can always use `&` with many filters - `mask = (df['Date'] != 'Off day') & (df['Date'] != 'Annual') & ...`. OR you can create function which check value and return True of False and use `mask = df['Date'].apply(my_func)`

Comment: could you please help me in creating the func as i'm a new learner in python

Comment: BTW: you can also use `apply` to run function which make all at once - it checks if it is text `"off day", "Annual"` and return this text, and if it is not text then it returns converted values.

Comment: could you provide me with this apply func to use it at once

Comment: I added `&`, `|`, `~` to current code in question.

Comment: I added example with `apply`

Comment: when i try to use the funck i found the below error (`return datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%H:%M %p')

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime`)

Comment: I used `dataframe` with `stings` - so I had to convert `string` to `datetime` - but it seems you already have `datetime` so you need only convert to `string` - `strftime('%H:%M %p')`. All this problem is because you didn't create minimal working code and we have to use own example data.